# How to do function composition?

Tags: java, java-8

While rather impatiently waiting for Java 8 release and after reading brilliant ['State of the Lambda' article from Brian Goetz](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html) I noticed that [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29) was not covered at all.

As per above article, in Java 8 the following should be possible:

```
// having classes Address and Person
public class Address {

    private String country;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
}

public class Person {

    private Address address;

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}

// we should be able to reference their methods like
Function<Person, Address> personToAddress = Person::getAddress;
Function<Address, String> addressToCountry = Address::getCountry;
```

Now if I would like to compose these two functions to have a function mapping `Person` to country, how can I achieve this in Java 8?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are `default` interface functions `Function::andThen` and `Function::compose`:

```
Function<Person, String> toCountry = personToAddress.andThen(addressToCountry);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed this is what I was interested in, thus accepting your answer :)

Comment: Just yesterday I was trying to get almost exactly the same as this, but I had an `IntFunction`---and it has nothing but `apply`. I wonder why...

Answer (score 23):

There is one flaw in using `compose` and `andThen`. You have to have explicit variables, so you can't use method references like this:

```
(Person::getAddress).andThen(Address::getCountry)
```

It won't be compiled. What a pity!

But you can define an utility function and use it happily:

```
public static <A, B, C> Function<A, C> compose(Function<A, B> f1, Function<B, C> f2) {
        return f1.andThen(f2);
    }

compose(Person::getAddress, Address::getCountry)
```

Comment: Good point - it's really a pity that it doesn't work this way :) However it's possible to invoke `andThen` method by using explicit cast on first method reference: `((Function<Person, Address>) Person::getAddress).andThen(Address:getCountry)` - still looks ugly, but it's a one-liner already. Please also note that type of second method reference it deducted automatically so no need for explicit cast

Comment: @Yura, guys, what's wrong with `Function<Person, String> fn = p -> p.getAddress().getCountry();`? It's shorter than using this invented `compose` or even not working `(Person::getAddress).andThen(Address::getCountry)`

Comment: @TagirValeev yes - you're right, that's another simple solution to mentioned problem :) However to me, `andThen` and `compose` are more interesting from the functional programming point of view

Comment: `compose` in this answer uses order of application of functions reversed from traditional: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition