# Invoke a method from a lambda-function's result

Tags: java, lambda

I have an object (`Adult`) with another object (`Child`) as a parameter. I am trying to write a `Function` that will return the child's name if given the adult.

I wrote this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Function<Adult, Object> adult_name_f = Adult::getName;
    Function<Adult, Object> adult_child_f = Adult::getChild;
    Function<Adult, Object> child_name_f = Adult::getChild.getName;
}

static class Adult {
    String name;
    Child child;

    public Child getChild() {
        return child;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

static class Child {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

but (obviously) `Adult::getChild.getName` is not a valid `Function`.

Is there a way to return the name of the child if given the adult?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should specify the appropriate return type of the `Function`.

```
Function<Adult, String> adult_name_f = Adult::getName;
Function<Adult, Child> adult_child_f = Adult::getChild;
```

You can then use the [`Function.andThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) method to create the third `Function`.

```
Function<Adult, String> child_name_f = adult_child_f.andThen(Child::getName);
```

Alternatively, and more commonly done, to make a method chain, you can define the `Function` using a lambda expression. You can even use lambda expressions for the first two, but method reference is better (less generated code).

```
Function<Adult, String> adult_name_f = a -> a.getName();
Function<Adult, Child> adult_child_f = a -> a.getChild();
Function<Adult, String> child_name_f = a -> a.getChild().getName();
```

*Test*

```
Adult mary = new Adult("Mary", new Child("Jesus"));
System.out.println(adult_name_f.apply(mary));  // prints: Mary
System.out.println(adult_child_f.apply(mary)); // prints: Test$Child@XXXXXXXX
System.out.println(child_name_f.apply(mary));  // prints: Jesus
```

Comment: Great answer. In my 'XY Problem', the functions are in a `List` and are iterated over. So I can't specify a proper return type. Either way, your answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is just to use a lambda.

```
Function<Adult, Object> child_name_f = adult -> adult.getChild().getName();
```

Note that this is the syntax of what Java calls a "lambda".  The syntax you used in your question is a *method reference*, not a lambda, but the two are closely related.  A method reference can always be expressed as a lambda.  Thus:

```
Function<Adult, Object> adult_name_f = Adult::getName;
```

is equivalent to

```
Function<Adult, Object> adult_name_f = adult -> adult.getName();
```

[There may be differences in how they're implemented, but the effect is the same for all practical purposes.]

When you want to call two methods, there's no simple way to do this with  method reference syntax, but a lambda works just fine.

See [How to do function composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834611/how-to-do-function-composition) for some other ideas of how you can create a function composition from two method references.  I think those answers are interesting, but in real life I'd still use the lambda.