# Any reason for using compose() instead of lambda expressions?

Tags: java, java-8

I was comparing the use of [`compose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#compose-java.util.function.Function-) default method with its equivalent  lambda expression and couldn't find any reason why prefering the former.

Maybe the reason is related to code expressiveness or functional style programming, as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834611/how-to-do-function-composition#comment53516499_32838924)

However, comparing the two approaches to solve the question [How to do function composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19834611/1140754) I see only disadvantages in using `compose()` instead of lambda expressions.

1st approach with `compose()` according to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19837537/1140754):

```
Function<Person, Address> personToAddress = Person::getAddress;
Function<Address, String> addressToCountry = Address::getCountry;
Function<Person, String> toCountry = addressToCountry.compose(personToAddress);
```

2nd approach with a lambda expression:

```
Function<Person, String> toCountry = p -> p.getAddress().getCountry();
```

Why do I prefer the second one? First, it is less verbose . Second, it does not require the explicit auxiliary variables `personToAddress` and `addressToCountry`.

So, is there any reason for using `compose()` instead of using a lambda explicitly?

Comment: The second one is appropriate when the two functions have been passed to you. i.e. they already exist.

Comment: In your simple example you know both how to get address from a person and how to get country from address. But what if you don't know how to get an address? What if `Person` has `List<Address>` and you don't know which one you are requested? Then you can request a mapper from client callsite and compose the answer.

Comment: Just to nit-pick, the local variables are not strictly required.  You could use a cast to link the method reference to the `Function` type

Answer (score 2):

One reason is if you do not create one or even both of the functions in the same piece of code, but get them passed in from somewhere else. Then you can either write a lambda that calls `apply()` on the given function(s), or use `compose()`, which would probably be cleaner.