# How to change lambda expression to method reference

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I need help regarding changing lambda expression to method reference:

lambda expression:

```
intervalCodes.stream().forEach(code -> {
            modProfile.addIntervalUsageCode(createIntervalCode(code));
          });
```

Can I change the above expression to like this:

```
intervalCodes.stream().forEach(modProfile::addIntervalUsageCode(createIntervalCode));
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: My suggestion: leave the code as is.  You're calling two methods, so you can't change it to a single method reference.  You could try some kind of function composition (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834611/how-to-do-function-composition), but that's not likely to improve your code.

Comment: If you want to be concise, remove the obsolete braces and if `intervalCodes` is a `Collection`, omit the Stream operation, which is unnecessary, if all you want to do, is `forEach`: `intervalCodes.forEach( code -> modProfile.addIntervalUsageCode(createIntervalCode(code)));`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `createIntervalCode()` is a side-effect-free instance method, you can split your lambda into two method references:

```
intervalCodes.stream()
        .map(this::createIntervalCode)
        .forEach(modProfile::addIntervalUsageCode);
```

If it's a static method, use `ClassName::createIntervalCode`.

Comment: `createIntervalCode` has a parameter `code` as stated in OP's question: `code -> { modProfile.addIntervalUsageCode(createIntervalCode(code));}`. Will the method reference still work?

Comment: @walen Certainly. `map()` expects a `Function`, which takes an input parameter.