# Method reference - invalid method reference - cannot be reference from static context

Tags: java, java-8

I have following piece of code

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
joiner.add("Something");
Function<StringJoiner,Integer> lengthFunc =  StringJoiner::length;
Function<CharSequence,StringJoiner> addFunc = StringJoiner::add;
```

Last line cause an error

```
Error:(54, 53) java: invalid method reference
  non-static method add(java.lang.CharSequence) cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I understand that this method can't be used in static way and I should have something like :

```
Function<CharSequence,StringJoiner> addFunc = joiner::add;
```

instead. However I can't understand why third line, with `StringJoiner::length;` is for java compiler perfectly correct. Can someboedy explain me why is that ?

Comment: Now, if you'd instead used `joiner::add` that _would_ be a valid `Function`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `StringJoiner.length` takes zero arguments, so the method reference overall takes a `StringJoiner` (the arbitrary instance) and returns an `Integer`. In other words, the first assigned method ref is equivalent to:

```
Function<StringJoiner, Integer> lengthFunc = new Function<StringJoiner, Integer>() {

       @Override
        public Integer apply(StringJoiner stringJoiner) {
            return stringJoiner.length;
        }
}
```

You would call this `Function` as follows:

```
StringJoiner sj1 = ...  // an arbitrary StringJoiner
int sjLength1 = lengthFunc.apply(sj1);
```

In contract, `StringJoiner.add(CharSequence)` takes one argument, so overall the `Function` would have to take (1) the arbirary instance of `StringJoiner`, (2) the `CharSequence` and return a `StringJoiner`.

You can instead assign the reference to a `BiFunction` which does that:

```
BiFunction<StringJoiner, CharSequence, StringJoiner> addFunc = StringJoiner::add;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
BiFunction<StringJoiner, CharSequence, StringJoiner> addFunc = new BiFunction<StringJoiner, CharSequence, StringJoiner>() {

       @Override
        public StringJoiner apply(StringJoiner stringJoiner, CharSequence charSequence) {
            return stringJoiner.add(charSequence);
        }
}
```

and would be used as follows:

```
StringJoiner sj1 = ...  // an arbitrary StringJoiner
sj1 = addFunc.apply(sj1, "a"); // no need to re-assign, but just to show the return type
```

Comment: what does mean arbitraty instance of StringJoiner ? I see that it is treated as object type on which the apply method will be called, but I'm not sure how it works

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło I've elaborated with how they are equivalent using pure anonymous classes. By arbitrary instance, I mean some instance that would be used in the context of an invocation to the method reference.

Comment: Thanks this is now clear for me. Great example how it would look like as implementation of anonymous functions.

Comment: one more question comes into my mind, what if i want to assign in the same way a function which takes two parameters as an argument ? Should I then write my own functional interface like `TripleFunction<StringJoiner,CharSerquence,Integer,StringJoiner> someFunc=StringJoiner:addWithSomeInteger `  ?

Comment: @ArturSkrzydło Yes you may have to write your own functional interface or use another workaround. You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400210/java-8-where-is-trifunction-and-kin-in-java-util-function-or-what-is-the-alt.

Comment: To add that I personally would avoid a `TriFunction` (because it would make code more complicated) and make it more like a composite function where first I append the `Integer` to the `CharSequence`, and then call the original `BiFunction`.

Answer (score 12):

```
Function<StringJoiner,Integer> lengthFunc =  StringJoiner::length;
```

`lengthFunc` is a Function that takes a `StringJoiner` and returns an `Integer`. Therefore any instance method of `StringJoiner` that takes nothing and returns an `Integer` matches this interface. The instance of which the method is called will be the `StringJoiner` required by the `Function<StringJoiner,Integer>`.

On the other hand in

```
Function<CharSequence,StringJoiner> addFunc = StringJoiner::add
```

`addFunc` is a `Function` that takes a `CharSequence` and returns `StringJoiner`. No instance method of `StringJoiner` matches this interface, since the function doesn't have an input `StringJoiner` instance to apply the `add` method on.

You would need a `BiFunction` to match the signature of `StringJoiner::add` :

```
BiFunction<StringJoiner,CharSequence,StringJoiner> addFunc = StringJoiner::add;
```

Comment: This is explained really well.