# A recursive lambda TriFunction

Tags: java, recursion, lambda

Is that the best way to implement a "TriFunction" without declaring an own Interface? And how is that construct called?

```java
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Rec {
    public static Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function>> myPowerTriFunction = x -> y -> f -> y == 0 ? 1 : x * (Integer) ((Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function>>) f).apply(x).apply(y - 1).apply(f);
    public static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> myPowerBiFunction = (x, y) -> (Integer) myPowerTriFunction.apply(x).apply(y).apply(myPowerTriFunction);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myPowerBiFunction.apply(3, 5)); // Prints 243
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you not want to define your own interface? It would take less time than it took to write this question.

Comment: It seems to me like you've spec'd out requirements for a bi-function.  Your example takes in 2 arguments and returns a value, which is what a bi-function does.  You've hidden some of the complexity in the function, but that doesn't really make it a tri-function.  A tri-function would take 3 values and return 1.  If that's what you need, I think you would want/need to create an interface.  A good example of doing that can be found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649473/2124562.

Comment: This is recursive, so it's not really a duplicate of the other question, is it?

Comment: If you want to make `Function` objects that are recursive, try something like the Y combinator. Here's a basic Java implementation  - https://repl.it/repls/GenuineSeashellBootstrapping (Note: this isn't the actual Y-combinator, which would require defining an interface, since it uses a recursive type)

Comment: Related: [Implement recursive lambda function using Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429667/implement-recursive-lambda-function-using-java-8)

Comment: @user Yes, this isn't really a duplicate of the other question... Maybe this question could be reopened... Thanks at all for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a technique called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). The basic idea is that a function of two or more arguments `f(x, y)` can be represented as a function that returns a function `f(x)(y)`.

For example here's a "curried" function that adds 3 numbers:

```
public static Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Integer>>>
    sum3 = x -> y -> z -> x + y + z;
```

This style does not really suit Java because a key philosophy of the language is that *names are meaningful*. Creating anonymous functions goes against this idea.

In your own code, you should not use raw types such as `Function`. If you don't know/care about the type, use a wildcard `?`:

```
public static Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<?,?>>> myPowerTriFunction;
```

Comment: I know this is the accepted answer, but it doesn't address the fact that the OP wants a recursive function