# How to declare a function that takes three params and returns a value

Tags: java, functional-interface

For instance if I wanted to declare similar lambda to the following method:

```
boolean isXyz(String a, int b, boolean c) {
...
}
```

Trying

```
Function<String,Integer,Booleean,Boolean> isXyz = ...
```

Results in a compilation error:

```
X.java:3: error: wrong number of type arguments; required 2
```

Comment: `Function` is just a convenient interface in the standard Java library.  You can always make your own if you want more flexibility, just the same way you can make more classes.

Comment: That first answer in the dupe is so rambly... Just copy the first bit of this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649473/1898563

Comment: @Michael the problem is I would have to to "pre" declare the interface, but if I want to use it right there the first answer it works fine, e.g.  say `(String,String) -> String` would be `Function<String,Function<String,String>> f2 = x -> y -> x + y`
Ugly as hell but "works" .. and then `val result = f2.apply("hello").apply("world");`

Comment: Hard to say what you should do because you really haven't given us any context. That might technically work but I'd say it's not likely to be idiomatic java

Comment: Oh I know... I know the Java way to add two strings would be `String f(String a, String b) { return a + b;}`. I was more in the way to learn the capabilities of lambdas

Comment: Added my answer there with what I've learnt https://stackoverflow.com/a/66448961/20654