# Parametrise a Runnable object at runtime

Tags: java, lambda, runnable, functional-interface

I have a Runnable task (doSomething) that I need to parametrise depending on who calls run().

```
    Class SomeClass {
    
        Public void foo(ScheduledExecutorService execService, ){
            ...
            Runnable doSomething = () -> {
                /*Code that I DON’T want to duplicate*/
                ...
                /* small piece of code that I need to parametrise */
            };
            ...
        
            // after someDelayInSeconds doSomething.run() will be called
            execService.schedule(doSomething, someDelayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

            // this might or might not call doSomething.run()
            bar(doSomething); 
    
            ...
        
        }

        private void bar(Runnable doSomething){

           ...
           if(/* some conditions are met */)
              doSomething.run();
           ...
        }
    }
```

So far the only alternative I have is to transform the anonymous class into a named class and create two objects with the required parameters.

Would there be a more elegant way?

Comment: Where are the parameters coming from?

Comment: The parameters will come from the invoker and these will denote who and why run() got invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change `doSomething` to a `Consumer` that accepts your parameters:

```
public void foo(ScheduledExecutorService execService) {
    Consumer<YourParams> doSomething = (params) -> {
        /*Code that I DON’T want to duplicate*/
        /* small piece of code that I need to parametrise */
        // use params
    };

    // after someDelayInSeconds doSomething.run() will be called
    YourParams asyncParams = /* parameters for async execution */;
    execService.schedule(() -> doSomething.accept(asyncParams), someDelayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // this might or might not call doSomething.run()
    bar(doSomething);

}

private void bar(Consumer<YourParams> doSomething) {
    if (/* some conditions are met */) {doSomething.accept(otherParams);}
}
```

In the scheduled execution you then transform `doSomething` into a `Runnable` by passing the default parameters for asynchronous execution, while in `bar()` you pass the alternative parameters of your choice directly.

Comment: This helped thanks! 

I ended-up using a BiConsumer as I had two parameters. In the case of N parameters the answer from @tavark gives a good hint. Alternatively something like this can be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649473/2022175

Comment: If you have N parameters you can always wrap them in a parameter object, or indeed implement a custom functional interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if this is what you are looking for:

```
  // provide config 
  Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
  config.put( "someKey", "someValue" );

  Consumer<Map<String, String>> consumer = cfg -> {
     Runnable doSth = () -> {
        if ( cfg.get( "someKey" ).equals( "someValue" ) ) {

        }
     };
     doSth.run();
  };

  // apply different configurations depending on your needs
  consumer.accept( config );
```

Comment: Not sure. But the Consumer with the nested anonymous Runnable might be a good hint. I'll think about it.

Comment: Thanks @Tavark. This was actually a good hint.